# Problems with php pagination function

Tags: php, mysql

I have two php files:
1. functions.php
2. index.php

The functions.php file has a series of functions that query MySQL database to produce different result sets. For example, i have two functions; one that returns all data whose year 2016, and the other that returns all the data whose year is 2015.

For both queries i desire to have php pagination for the result sets returned. An example of the function that returns results for all data whose years are 2015 and 2016 looks like this:

```
       function get2015(){

    $con = dbConnect();

    $refs_per_page = 20;

    $query = "select * from mytable where year = 2015";
    $sql=$con->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();
    $total = $sql->rowCount();
    $pages = ceil($total/$refs_per_page);
    echo "$total <br>";

    if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET["page"])){
    $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
    }//endif


    if($page =="" || $page ==1){
    $page=0;
    }
    else{
    $page = ($page * $refs_per_page)-$refs_per_page;
    }
    //
    $query = "select * from mytable where year = 2015 limit $page, $refs_per_page";
    $sql=$con->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();

    $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while ($row=$sql->fetch()){
        $title = $row['title'];
        $authors = $row['authors'];
        echo "<b>$title</b>" . "<br>" . $authors . "<p>";
        }



        //
        for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){

            ?><a href = "index.php?page= <?php echo $x;?>" style="text-decoration:none"> <?php echo $x;?> </a> <?php
    }
    }
//function get records for 2016
function get2016(){

$con = dbConnect();

$refs_per_page = 20;

$query = "select * from mytable where year = 2016";
$sql=$con->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$total = $sql->rowCount();
$pages = ceil($total/$refs_per_page);
echo "$total <br>";

if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET["page"])){
$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
}//endif


if($page =="" || $page ==1){
$page=0;
}
else{
$page = ($page * $refs_per_page)-$refs_per_page;
}
//
$query = "select * from mytable where year = 2016 limit $page, $refs_per_page";
$sql=$con->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();

$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($row=$sql->fetch()){
    $title = $row['title'];
    $authors = $row['authors'];
    echo "<b>$title</b>" . "<br>" . $authors . "<p>";
    }



    //
    for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){

        ?><a href = "index.php?page= <?php echo $x;?>" style="text-decoration:none"> <?php echo $x;?> </a> <?php
}
}
```

The code in index.php code looks like this

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
$page = $_GET["page"];
if($page){
 if($page=="get2015"){
    get2015();
    }
if($page=="get2016"){
    get2016();
    }
}
?>
<html>
Archive<br>
<a href="index.php?page=get2015"> 2015</a><br>
<a href="index.php?page=get2016"> 2016</a><br>
</html>
<?php ?>
```

The first page renders okay but when i click on the second page the page goes blank. @Syed below has suggested the use of an offset variable, which while useful does the same thing as the $page variable in the code above. How do i get pagination to work? I highly suspect that the problem is how i am calling the pages on index.php

Comment: Why first request has page=get2015 and second request page=2?

Comment: You can't use the same GET parameter for 2 different things. `$_GET['page']` in the second link is `2`, but you only check pagination if it's `get2015`.

Comment: @Jon Stirling are you suggesting two separate GET parameters?

Comment: @tapeli Well, it's your only option if you want to keep your code as it stands without having to changes loads.

Comment: @Jon Stirling any suggestions in terms of code, how i can overcome this?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: In the absence of an order by query, LIMIT is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Your sould make `$offset` variable and minus 1 from it and then multiply by `$per_page`

**For example**

User in `index.php` your offset variable calculate like that.

```
// offset should be equal to 0 and query should be 
// SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE year='2015' LIMIT 0, 20
(page=1 - 1) = 0 * $per_page = 20
```

User in `index.php?page=2` your offset variable calculate like that.

```
// offset should be equal to 20 and query should be 
// SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE year='2015' LIMIT 20, 20
(page=2 - 1) = 1 * $per_page = 20 

// offset should be equal to 40 and query should be 
// SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE year='2015' LIMIT 40, 20
(page=3 - 1) = 2 * $per_page = 40 

$sql = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE year='%s'", $_GET['year']);
// Query to database and store in pages variable
$total_record = $con->query($sql)->result();

$page = ( isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$per_page = 20;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$pages = ceil($total/$per_page);

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE year='%s' LIMIT %s, %s", $_GET['year'], $offset, $per_page);

// QUERY TO DATABASE

for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++){

    if ($page == $i) {
        echo '<span class="active">'. $i .'</span>';
    }else{
        echo '<a href = "index.php?year="youryear"&page='. $i .'" style="text-decoration:none">' .$i .'</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Syed. Should all this code be written in index.php?

Comment: of-course all the code should be on the page where you want your result. in this case index.php

Comment: I have rephrased the question again. The solution you have suggested @Syed did not work for me.

Comment: your suggestion of the offset variable is good but tit performs the same function as the $page variable above. I have changed the question once again.

Comment: `?page=get2015` it is not valid it should be `year=2015&page=1` and here you should perform your query based on year ok

Comment: Thank you @Syed, the $_GET['year'] array causes this error -> Notice: Undefined index: year in /var/www/pagination/index.php on line 6